# How can I install the BannerPlugin Webpack plugin using npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'd like to install the [BannerPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/banner-plugin/) for Webpack 4.12 using npm.  However by trying `npm i --save-dev banner-plugin`, `bannerplugin` or `webpack-banner-plugin`... npm fails to fetch the package and install it.  I'm using npm 6.1.0 but the issue is most likely because I don't know what the package name actually is. 
 I've found install instructions for another similar package ([banner-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/banner-webpack-plugin)) only because npmjs.com has a convenient "install" tab off to the right showing the full install command string.  But I don't want to use this one.  I want to use BannerPlugin found on Webpack's [plugins](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/) list shown here.  How can I find the name of this package to be able to install it in my project?

Comment: Looks like it's part of webpack. Just `require('webpack').BannerPlugin()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of webpack, as you can see here. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/BannerPlugin.js

Just `require('webpack').BannerPlugin` and you are good to go.